# Not prompted to input the root password when installing mariadb-server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I just had a fresh install on my pc the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I tried to install MariaDB by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

The installation went smoothly but during the process I was not prompted to input the password for the mysql root account. After the installation I was unable to log into MariaDB (`mysql -u root -p`) and it showed the error message:

```
ERROR 1698 Access denied for user 'root'
```

Everything was a fresh install. The entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` were checked and all major components were enabled properly.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Does your terminal prompt have a `$` or a `#`? (I ask because normal users have  `$` in the prompt, but root has `#`)

Comment: @NickWeinberg I think the issue here is the database root password not the system root password

Comment: @steeldriver Ahh, ok. I was confused because of the "**sudo** apt-get" command and "not being asked to input the password for root". But I think you're right

Comment: @DavidFoerster I was trying to login as root in mariadb (not root in linux) by "mysql -u root -p"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mariadb package doesn't offer a configuration wizard during installation on Ubuntu 16.04.

Use the below command to have a mysql shell

```
sudo mysql -uroot
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thanks. But I remember earlier when I installed mariadb I was prompted to set the root password. Since when was it changed?

Comment: @user6133116: That contradicts the statement in your question. Which one is it. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm sorry, but I really don't see any contradiction. I think you might not have got the idea of my question.

Comment: “during the process [of the installation] I was **not** prompted to input the password for the mysql root account” (taken from your question, highlight by me) vs. “when I installed mariadb I was prompted to set the root password” (taken from your comment)

Comment: @DavidFoerster "But I remember EARLIER when I installed mariadb I was prompted to set the root password. Since when was it changed?"  Please pay attention to the word 'earlier' which I meant "some time ago, not this time". I was prompted to set the password for the database root account before, but not this time during this fresh install, hence the question posted in here.

Comment: It could also be some confusion made by my usage of the English language, as I'm not an English native speaker.  If that's the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly the type of clarification that I was looking for. I suspected this specific contextual meaning of “earlier” but didn't want to jump to conclusions. Sometimes people insert or omit a “not” by accident.

Comment: Worked for  `MariaDB version 10.0.25` on `Ubuntu 15.10`.

Comment: This doesn't work for MariaDB 10.3.22 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo mysql -u root`. You should be able to login this way.